# Unable to install Jekyll on Mac OSX 10.9.1 with xcode and rvm installed

Tags: ruby, macos, rubygems, rvm, jekyll

Not having any luck installing Jekyll on Mac OSX 10.9.1

I have rvm installed and also Xcode 5.0.2.

When I run `gem install jekyll` it tells me...

> Permission denied -
>   /Users/Vivid/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/extensions/x86_64-darwin-12

I then ran `sudo gem install jekyll` and I then get:

```
ERROR:  Error installing jekyll:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/Vivid/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/bin/ruby extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make  clean

make
gcc-4.2 -I. -I/Users/Vivid/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-darwin12.2.0 -I/Users/Vivid/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/Users/Vivid/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE   -fno-common -I/Users/Vivid/.rvm/usr/include -fno-common -pipe  -o porter.o -c porter.c
make: gcc-4.2: No such file or directory
make: *** [porter.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/Vivid/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/fast-stemmer-1.0.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/Vivid/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/extensions/x86_64-darwin-12/1.9.1/fast-stemmer-1.0.2/gem_make.out
```

This is the contents of `/Users/Vivid/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/fast-stemmer-1.0.2/ext/gem_make.out`:

```
/Users/Vivid/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin/ruby extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make
compiling porter.c
make: /usr/bin/gcc-4.2: No such file or directory
make: *** [porter.o] Error 1
```

Something is clearly not right. Any advice would be magic, cheers.

Comment: I'd like to know what version of Ruby I should be using. Should this make a difference?

I'm currently running: `ruby 1.9.2p320 (2012-04-20 revision 35421) [x86_64-darwin12.2.0]`

Answer (score 3):

You need to install `gcc-4.2`. Make sure you have [Homebrew installed](http://brew.sh) and run

```
brew install apple-gcc42
```

Make sure you see happy output when you run:

```
which gcc-4.2
```

Then try re-running:

```
sudo gem install jekyll
```

Boom! Installed.

Comment: Yeah, this helped a lot. I did have to run these commands first
`brew update`
`brew tap homebrew/dupes`
`brew install apple-gcc42`

...then worked I was to successfully follow your instructions.